# Ember validation firing too late

Tags: validation, ember.js

I am using Ember 1.7 and have a model with a validation on it.

Using the input helper, I'm binding an action to the `on="key-press"` trigger.

In the action fired (within my controller) I'm calling `this.get('myModalInstance').validate()` and I have handlers setup for pass and fail.

What's odd is that the validation seems to fire with the previous value I've typed.

So if my validation says `numericality: { greaterThan: 0, lessThanOrEqualTo: 90 }` when I type `9`, it validates ok, when I type in `91` it validates ok, and when I type in `911` it fails validation.

This seems one key press too late as far as I can see. Is this a known / common issue? Are there are tips for avoiding this issue?

**EDIT**
I should add that I've also tried to bind my validation failure css class to the errors object for a field like this:

```
{{input value=myValue classBinding=":form-input myValue.errors:validation-failure"}}
```

Which is displaying strange behaviour (such as sometimes not applying the class at all, sometimes applying it when I'm expecting (such as deleting the contents on an input which has `presence: true` set) and sometimes validating when I change a different control on the form.

Comment: I've found out that `key-press` fires before the value has changed (hence my confusion) and for some reason `key-up` & `key-down` don't fire at all :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a keypress event, if you want to validate some value (or few) when they updated. Use [observer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/object-model/observers/) (read "Observers and asynchrony" section thoroughly, it's very important and shows how to avoid such lags) instead: observe changes to fields you are interested in and validate.

Or, if you want to use one of jquery validation plugins, you can create a [component](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/), call it validated-form for example, and use a jquery plugin for validation. These plugins usualy handle all needed events themself. Simple version of such component (should work with [this](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'form',
    onSubmit: null,
    validationRules: {},
    validationMessages: {},
    didInsertElement() {
        const form = this.$();
        form.validate({
            submitHandler: () => {
                if (this.get('onSubmit')) {
                    this.sendAction('onSubmit');
                }
            },
            rules: this.get('validationRules'),
            messages: this.get('validationMessages')
        });
    }
});
```

And in template you use it like this:

```
{{#validated-form validationRules=validationRules}}
    Form fields here
{{/validated-form}}
```

If you are interested in reasons why your solution doesn't work, I believe that's because ember's input component uses `input` event to update binded value, and `input` event is being fired after `keypress`

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I will give this a go. Coming from a non ember background my thoughts were that I need to call validate on some kind of event. Presumably the psuedo logic would be something like: Observer field x -> validate field x -> check errors property -> set bound css class to results of validation?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald yes, smth like that

Comment: It seems that the validation is performed automatically on my models. So actually all i needed to do was bind the css classes correctly.